# JVM freeze resolved by pstack

Tags: java, jvm, pstack

I am facing a strange problem solution: Our JVM (1.6) freezes from time to time (probably because of blocking threads or garbage collection) when running an application server. If we run the pstack command, the problem resolves.

Can somebody explain how pstack can resolve this freeze? I want to understand how a command that "only" reads stack traces is able to unblock/unfreeze the JVM in order to understand more about the freezes.

Comment: OS/kernel version/JVM version?

Comment: Do you face the same behaviour if you connect with `jconsole`? If not then connect with jconsole and check the running threads before and at the moment you run the pstack command.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Are you using the latest Java 6? do you really need to be using such an old version? i.e. Java 8 does a better job or responding while GC-ing.